# CMake is unable to locate include files

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clion, mingw-w64

[image]

The `CMakeLists.txt` file in `base` folder:

```
# leaf files
add_library(Account "")

target_sources(Account
  PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Account.cpp
  PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Account.h
        )

target_include_directories( Account
        PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/initial/initial
  )
```

The above is generating the following build error:

```
====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.2.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\pc\git\cmake_test\cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 3
Scanning dependencies of target Account
[ 37%] Built target Initial
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/models/CMakeFiles/SavingsAccount.dir/SavingsAccount.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/models/base/CMakeFiles/Account.dir/Account.cpp.obj
C:\Users\pc\git\cmake_test\src\models\SavingsAccount.cpp:6:10: fatal error: initial/initial/initial.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <initial/initial/initial.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
C:\Users\pc\git\cmake_test\src\models\base\Account.cpp:6:10: fatal error: initial/initial/initial.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <initial/initial/initial.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [src\models\CMakeFiles\SavingsAccount.dir\build.make:83: src/models/CMakeFiles/SavingsAccount.dir/SavingsAccount.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:231: src/models/CMakeFiles/SavingsAccount.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make[2]: *** [src\models\base\CMakeFiles\Account.dir\build.make:83: src/models/base/CMakeFiles/Account.dir/Account.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:204: src/models/base/CMakeFiles/Account.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

I discovered that this happens when a header file is included from a different parent folder or a child of a different parent folder.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you try using `"core/index.hh"` instead of `<core/index.hh>`

Comment: Try that and see if it resolves the issue. Usually it works. Maybe create a new small project with 2 or 3 headers files and then try including them using `"core/demo.h"` to test this instead of testing this on a large project.

Comment: That's why I'm saying to create a new small project with 2 or 3 header files and test this out on that new small project. If my suggestion works then it will confirm that it will also work for any larger project and that it is the issue.

Comment: @JasonLiam, I recreated the problem with a minimal example. I found out that, this happens when a header file is included from a different parent folder or from its child of a different parent folder.

Comment: Ok then most probably you're missing a `./` or a `/` in the beginning of the include. For example you can try `"./initial/initial/initial.h"` or something like that. See if this works.

Comment: For make `#include <initial/initial/initial.h>` to work, you need to have `src` among include directories. I don't see a place in your code where you add this directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, In which file should I include `src`?

Comment: You could add it e.g. in the file which creates `Account` target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, https://github.com/mns-csharp/cmake_test

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `#include` directive with the `<>` brackets. The obvious issue is within these lines of code:

```
target_include_directories( Account
        PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/initial/initial #<-- here to be precise
  )
```

Bare in mind that whatever directory you point to it will get treated like a system path.

You are obviously (as you yourself know) **not** pointing to the correct folder. **Treat CMake like you would any other programming language**, i.e. experiment with it and debug the variables you use! The easiest way to debug this is to add a

```
message(STATUS  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

That way you will know for sure if you are pointing to the correct folder.
Currently I assume that `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is pointing to the root folder (where your main `CMakeLists.txt` is), because I would expect CLion to start building from the root `CMakeLists.txt` file (otherwise the existence of that file would be pointless) i.e. **that is the top-level of your source tree**. Thus the path should most likely be `src/` as **Tsyvarev already pointed out**. But please confirm this by debugging it.

This would have been more obvious if you'd operate from the CLI, but
because you are running this task from CLion **you don't know for sure what is the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`**.

This is because this is dependent on either the `CWD` from which you call `cmake -B[build-folder]` or what you specify to the `-S` flag in `cmake -S[source_folder] -B[build_folder]`.

For more info on specifying the source-tree [check this link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html).
Additionally check out [CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html), [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) and [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html)